# How should you represent the data in a BigInt (large number) class?

Tags: c++, biginteger, bigint, largenumber

I'm trying to implement a `BigInteger` class in C++.

How can the base data be represented? The most naive way is to have a fixed or dynamic array of `char` and store each digit of an integer in a `char`. Is there any better way?

Comment: If you want to perform the multi-precision math yourself, then I suggest you take a look at Donald Knuth's [Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming). I believe Volume II, Seminumerical Algorithms, Chapter 4, Multiple Precision Arithmetic, is what you are interested in. Also see [How to add 2 arbitrarily sized integers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2926219/608639), which provides code for some C++ libraries and OpenSSL.

Comment: Using `char` is indeed not the best, `std::uint64_t` would make the math on 64 bits at once with the CPU instead of having to deal with 8 x `char`.

Answer (score 16):

There are a bunch of suggestions here for existing implementations:  [C++ handling very large integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124332/c-handling-very-large-integers)

If you have to implement your own (e.g. for homework), then you have to decide the best way, and how "big" you need to handle.  You could use an array of DWORDs, and handle overflowing from one to the next.

Although, for some of the Project Euler stuff, I actually implemented a BigNumber class built on a string.  It turned out to be the simplest to implement for +-*/, and scaled to significantly longer numbers than I could get with a few `unsigned long long`s.  And the performance was perfectly adequate for solving those puzzles.

So, you face a tradeoff between ease of implementation and optimal performance.  Have fun ;-)

Answer (score 9):

That's my decimal base implementation. string for the value and a bool for the sign (Note: notice that bool = true => the number is negative).
pretty much all the basic functions are here tested & ready to use.

*Pay Attention:* the bitwise operators were implemented a bit (sda-ka-dish) differently, all explained in the **getBinary()** function.

knock yourself out.

```
#include <string>
#ifndef AC1_INFINT_H
#define AC1_INFINT_H


class InfInt {
    std::string value;
    bool sign = 0;
public:


InfInt();
InfInt(const std::string&);
InfInt(long int);
InfInt operator=(long int);
explicit operator int() const;

std::string getValue() const;
bool getSign() const;
InfInt operator+(const InfInt&) const;
InfInt operator-(const InfInt&) const;
InfInt operator*(const InfInt&) const;
InfInt operator/(const InfInt&) const;
InfInt operator%(const InfInt&) const;

bool operator<(const InfInt&) const;
bool operator>(const InfInt&) const;
bool operator<=(const InfInt&) const;
bool operator>=(const InfInt&) const;
bool operator==(const InfInt&) const;
void operator+=(const InfInt&);
void operator-=(const InfInt&);
void operator++();
void operator--();
//void operator++();
//void operator--();


//BitWise
InfInt operator&(const InfInt&) const;
InfInt operator<<(const InfInt&) const;
InfInt operator>>(const InfInt& a) const;
void operator<<=(const InfInt&);
void operator>>=(const InfInt&);
void operator&=(const InfInt&);
InfInt operator^(const InfInt&) const;
InfInt operator|(const InfInt&) const;




unsigned long length() const;
std::string align(const unsigned long) const;
void initFromBinary(const std::string);





private:

std::string getBinary() const;

std::string subtract(const InfInt&) const;
std::string add(const InfInt&) const;
void setSign(const bool);
InfInt alignLeft(const unsigned long) const;

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const InfInt&);


#endif //AC1_INFINT_H
```

and the cpp file (I guess Ctrl + F will do better if you look for a specific operator):

```
//
// Created by NSC on 11/7/18.
//
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "LargeIntegers.h"

unsigned long InfInt::length() const{
    if (value == "0")
    return 0;
    return value.length();
}

InfInt::InfInt(){
    value = "0";
}

InfInt::InfInt(const std::string &s) {
    unsigned long start = s.find_first_not_of("0-");

    if (!std::strcmp(&s[start],"")) {
    std::strcpy(&value[0], "0");
    }

    if(s[0] == '-') {
    sign = 1;
    }
    value = &s[start];
}

InfInt::InfInt(long int a) {
    sign =0;
    if (a < 0){
    sign = 1;
    a *= -1;
    }

    value = std::to_string(a);
}

InfInt InfInt::operator=(long int a){
    return *new InfInt(a);
}

std::string InfInt::getValue() const{
    return value;
}

bool InfInt::getSign() const{
    return sign;
}

void InfInt::setSign(const bool s){
    sign = s;
}

InfInt::operator int() const{
    int final = 0 ;
    int pow = 1;
    for (long i = length() - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
    final +=  pow * (value[i] - '0');
    pow*= 10;
    }
    if (sign)
    final *= -1;
    return final;
}

std::string InfInt::getBinary() const{
    //if the number is 0
    if (!length())
    return "0";
    InfInt temp = *new InfInt(value);
    //sign at the start and then from lsb to msb
    std::string result = "";
    result = result + (char)((int)sign + '0');
    std::string current;

    while (temp > 0){
    current=  (temp%2).getValue();
    if (current.length() == 0)
        result = result + "0";
    else
        result = result + current;
    temp = temp/2;
    }

    return result;
}

void InfInt::initFromBinary(const std::string b){
    sign = b[0] - '0';
    InfInt temp = 0;
    InfInt shift = 1;
    for (long i=1; i<b.length(); i++){
    temp += *new InfInt((int)(b[i] - '0')) * shift;
    shift = shift * 2;
    }

    value = temp.value;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const InfInt& a){
    if (a.length() == 0 || a.getValue()[0] == '0') {
    std::string zero = "0";
    return os << zero;
    }
    if (a.getSign())
    return os << "-" + a.getValue();
    else
    return os<< a.getValue();
}

std::string InfInt::align(const unsigned long l) const{
    std::string newStr = value;
    for (unsigned long i=0; i<l; i++){
    newStr = "0" + newStr;
    }
    return newStr;
}

InfInt InfInt::alignLeft(const unsigned long l ) const{
    std::string newStr = value;
    for (unsigned long i=0; i<l; i++){
    newStr = newStr + "0";
    }
    return newStr;
}

void InfInt::operator++(){
    *this+=1;
}

void InfInt::operator--(){
    *this= *this - 1;
}

//adding the values of the input w/o their sign
std::string InfInt::add(const InfInt & a) const {
    unsigned long numOfZeros = value.length() - a.length();
    std::string aligned = a.align(numOfZeros);
    //now this and a are in the same length

    std::string result;
    int x = 0;
    bool carry = 0;

    for (long i = value.length() -1; i>=0; i--){
    //according to the ascii table '0' = 0 + 48 so subtracting 48 is a more sufficient way to convert
    x=value[i] + aligned[i] - 96 + carry;
    carry = x/10;
    result = (char)(x%10 + 48) + result;
    }

    //in case of "overflow"
    if (carry)
    result = "1" + result;

    return result;
}

InfInt InfInt::operator+(const InfInt & a) const{
    //a + (-b) = a - b
    if (!getSign() && a.getSign()) {
    InfInt * temp = new InfInt(a.value);
    return *this - *temp;
    }

    //(-a) + b = b - a
    if (getSign() && !a.getSign()) {
    //temp is positive. temp = -a
    InfInt * temp = new InfInt(value);
    return a - *temp;
    }

    //a + b = b + a
    if (value.length() < a.length())
    return a.operator+(*this);

    std::string result = this->add(a);

    //(-a) + (-b) = -(a + b)
    if (getSign() && a.getSign())
    return *new InfInt('-' + result);

    return *new InfInt(result);
}

//when this function is called, we can be sure that a > b
std::string InfInt::subtract(const InfInt& a) const{

    if (a.length() > length())
    return a.subtract(*this);
    long numOfZeros = this->length() - a.length();
    std::string aligned = a.align(numOfZeros);
    //now this and a are in the same length

    std::string result = "";
    int x = 0;
    bool carry = 0;

    for (long i = value.length() -1; i>=0; i--){
    x=value[i] - aligned[i] - carry;
    carry = false;
    if (x < 0){
        x+=10;
        carry = true;
    }
    result = (char)(x + 48) + result;
    }

    return result;
}

InfInt InfInt::operator-(const InfInt &a) const{
    if (length() == 0)
    return a * *new InfInt(-1);
    if (a.length() == 0)
    return *this * *new InfInt(-1);
    //both positive
    if (!getSign() && !a.getSign()) {
    if (*this > a)
        return *new InfInt(this->subtract(a));

    // a - b = -(b - a)
    InfInt * result = new InfInt(a.subtract(*this));
    result->setSign(true);
    return *result;
    }

    //a - (-b) = a + b
    if (!getSign() && a.getSign())
    return *new InfInt(this->add(a));

    //(-a) - b = - (a + b)
    if (getSign() && !a.getSign()) {
    InfInt result = this->add(a);
    result.setSign(true);
    return result;
    }

    //(-a) - (-b) = b - a
    InfInt temp1 = *new InfInt(value);
    InfInt temp2 = *new InfInt(a.value);
    return temp2 - temp1;
//    if (a > *this)
//        return *new InfInt(a.subtract(*this));
//
//    InfInt * result = new InfInt(this->subtract(a));
//    result->setSign(true);
//    return *result;
}

void InfInt::operator+=(const InfInt& a){
    InfInt temp = *this + a;
    value = temp.value;
    sign = temp.sign;
}

void InfInt::operator-=(const InfInt& a){
    InfInt temp = *this - a;
    value = temp.value;
    sign = temp.sign;
}

InfInt InfInt::operator*(const InfInt& a) const{

    InfInt final = 0;
    std::string result;
    InfInt* temp;


    int carry;
    int current;

    //fast mult algorithm. the same we were taught in elementary.
    for(long i=length() - 1;i >= 0; i--){
    carry = 0;
    result = "";
    for (long j=a.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        current = (value[i] - '0') * (a.value[j] - '0') + carry;
        result = (char)(current % 10 + '0') + result;
        carry = current / 10;
    }

    if (carry > 0)
        result = (char)(carry + '0') + result;

    temp = new InfInt(result);
    final += *new InfInt(temp->alignLeft(length() - i - 1));
    }

    final.setSign(sign ^ a.sign);
    return final;
}

//long division implementation
InfInt InfInt::operator/(const InfInt& a) const {
    if (a.length() == 0 || a.getValue()[0] == '0') {
    throw "Devision By Zero";
    }

    //divider = |a|
    InfInt divider = *new InfInt(a.getValue());
    if (divider > *new InfInt(value))
    return *new InfInt();

    std::string result;
    int idx = 0;

    //temp is the part of the divided that's being currently focused
    InfInt temp = value[idx] - '0';
    while (temp < divider.value)
    temp = temp * 10 + (value[++idx] - '0');

    while(idx < length()) {

    if (temp == 0){
        result = result + "0";
        idx++;
    }
    else {
        // Find prefix of number that's larger
        // than a.value.


        InfInt multNum = 1;
        InfInt leftover = temp - divider;
        while (leftover >= divider) {
            leftover -= divider;
            multNum += 1;
        }

        leftover = temp - (multNum * divider);
        result = result + multNum.getValue();

        temp = leftover * 10 + (value[++idx] - '0');
        temp.setSign(false);
    }
    }
    // If a.value is greater than value
    if (result.length() == 0)
    return *new InfInt();

    InfInt final = *new InfInt(result);
    final.setSign(this->sign ^ a.getSign());
    return final;
}

InfInt InfInt::operator%(const InfInt& a) const {
    if (a.length() == 0 || a.getValue()[0] == '0') {
    throw "Modulo By Zero";
    }

    if (a > *this)
    return *new InfInt(*this);
    //divider = |a|
    InfInt divider = *new InfInt(a.getValue());

    if (divider > *new InfInt(value))
    return (*this + a) % a;
    std::string result;
    int idx = 0;
    InfInt leftover;

    InfInt temp = value[idx] - '0';
    while (temp < divider.value)
    temp = temp * 10 + (value[++idx] - '0');

    while(idx < length()) {
    // Find prefix of number that's larger
    // than a.value.


    InfInt multNum = 0;
    leftover = temp;
    while (leftover >= divider) {
        leftover -= divider;
        multNum += 1;
    }

    leftover = temp - (multNum * divider);
    leftover.setSign(false);

    temp = leftover * 10 + (value[++idx] - '0');
    }
    // If a.value is greater than value

    return leftover;
}

bool InfInt::operator<(const InfInt& a) const{
    if (getSign() && !a.getSign())
    return true;
    if (!getSign() && a.getSign())
    return false;

    unsigned long l1 = length(), l2 = a. length();

    //both positive
    if (!getSign() && !a.getSign()) {
    if (l1 > l2)
        return false;

    if (l1 < l2)
        return true;

    for (long i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        if (value[i] > a.value[i])
            return false;

        if (value[i] < a.value[i])
            return true;
    }
    }

    else {
    if (l1 > l2)
        return true;

    if (l1 < l2)
        return false;

    for (long i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        if (value[i] > a.value[i])
            return true;

        if (value[i] < a.value[i])
            return false;
    }
    }

    //equal
    return false;
}

bool InfInt::operator<=(const InfInt& a) const{
    if (getSign() && !a.getSign())
    return true;
    if (!getSign() && a.getSign())
    return false;

    unsigned long l1 = length(), l2 = a. length();

    //both positive
    if (!getSign() && !a.getSign()) {
    if (l1 > l2)
        return false;

    if (l1 < l2)
        return true;

    for (long i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        if (value[i] > a.value[i])
            return false;

        if (value[i] < a.value[i])
            return true;
    }
    }

    else {
    if (l1 > l2)
        return true;

    if (l1 < l2)
        return false;

    for (long i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        if (value[i] > a.value[i])
            return true;

        if (value[i] < a.value[i])
            return false;
    }
    }

    //equal
    return true;
}

bool InfInt::operator>(const InfInt& a) const{
    if (getSign() && !a.getSign())
    return false;
    if (!getSign() && a.getSign())
    return true;

    unsigned long l1 = length(), l2 = a. length();

    //both negative
    if (getSign() && a.getSign()) {
    if (l1 > l2)
        return false;

    if (l1 < l2)
        return true;

    for (long i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        if (value[i] > a.value[i])
            return false;

        if (value[i] < a.value[i])
            return true;
    }
    }

    else {
    if (l1 > l2)
        return true;

    if (l1 < l2)
        return false;

    for (long i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        if (value[i] > a.value[i])
            return true;

        if (value[i] < a.value[i])
            return false;
    }
    }

    //equal
    return false;
}

bool InfInt::operator>=(const InfInt& a) const{
    if (getSign() && !a.getSign())
    return false;
    if (!getSign() && a.getSign())
    return true;

    unsigned long l1 = length(), l2 = a. length();

    //both negative
    if (getSign() && a.getSign()) {
    if (l1 > l2)
        return false;

    if (l1 < l2)
        return true;

    for (long i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        if (value[i] > a.value[i])
            return false;

        if (value[i] < a.value[i])
            return true;
    }
    }

    else {
    if (l1 > l2)
        return true;

    if (l1 < l2)
        return false;

    for (long i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        if (value[i] > a.value[i])
            return true;

        if (value[i] < a.value[i])
            return false;
    }
    }

    //equal
    return true;
}

bool InfInt::operator==(const InfInt& a) const{

    if (length() == 0 && a.length() == 0)
    return true;

    //if the signs are not the same
    if (getSign() ^ a.getSign())
    return false;

    if (length() != a.length())
    return false;

    for(long i = 0; i < length(); i++){
    if (value[i] != a.value[i])
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void InfInt::operator<<=(const InfInt& a){

    InfInt result = *this << a;

    value = result.getValue();
    sign = result.getSign();
}

void InfInt::operator>>=(const InfInt& a){

    InfInt result = *this >> a;

    value = result.getValue();
    sign = result.getSign();
}

void InfInt::operator&=(const InfInt& a){
     InfInt temp = *this & a;
     value = temp.getValue();
     sign = temp.getSign();
}

InfInt InfInt::operator^(const InfInt& a) const{
    std::string b1 = this->getBinary();
    std::string b2 = a.getBinary();

    long l1 = b1.length();
    long l2 = b2.length();

    //adding zeros from right doesn't change the value of the number
    int numOfZeros;

    if (l1 > l2) {
    numOfZeros = l1- l2;
    for (int i=0; i < numOfZeros; i++)
        b2 = b2 + "0";
    }
    else if (l2 > l1) {
    numOfZeros = l2- l1;
    for (int i=0; i < numOfZeros; i++)
        b1 = b1 + "0";
    }

    std::string result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i<l1+1; i++){
    if (b1[i] == '1' ^ b2[i] == '1')
        result = result + "1";
    else
        result = result + "0";
    }

    InfInt final = *new InfInt();
    final.initFromBinary(result);
    return final;
}

InfInt InfInt::operator|(const InfInt& a) const{
    std::string b1 = this->getBinary();
    std::string b2 = a.getBinary();

    long l1 = b1.length();
    long l2 = b2.length();

    //adding zeros from right doesn't change the value of the number
    int numOfZeros;

    if (l1 > l2) {
    numOfZeros = l1- l2;
    for (int i=0; i < numOfZeros; i++)
        b2 = b2 + "0";
    }
    else if (l2 > l1) {
    numOfZeros = l2- l1;
    for (int i=0; i < numOfZeros; i++)
        b1 = b1 + "0";
    }

    std::string result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i<l1; i++){
    if (b1[i] == '1' || b2[i] == '1')
        result = result + "1";
    else
        result = result + "0";
    }

    InfInt final = *new InfInt();
    final.initFromBinary(result);
    return final;
}

InfInt InfInt::operator&(const InfInt& a) const {
    std::string b1 = this->getBinary();
    std::string b2 = a.getBinary();

    long l1 = b1.length();
    long l2 = b2.length();

    //adding zeros from right doesn't change the value of the number
    int numOfZeros;

    if (l1 > l2) {
    numOfZeros = l1- l2;
    for (int i=0; i < numOfZeros; i++)
        b2 = b2 + "0";
    }
    else if (l2 > l1) {
    numOfZeros = l2- l1;
    for (int i=0; i < numOfZeros; i++)
        b1 = b1 + "0";
    }

    std::string result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i<l1; i++){
    if (b1[i] == '1' && b2[i] == '1')
        result = result + "1";
    else
        result = result + "0";
    }

    InfInt final = *new InfInt();
    final.initFromBinary(result);
    return final;
}

InfInt InfInt::operator<<(const InfInt& a) const {
    std::string b = this->getBinary();
    std::string result = "";
    result = result + b[0];

    //adding 0's multiplies by 2
    for (InfInt i = 0; i < a; i+=1){
    result = result + "0";
    }

    //adding the original bits after adding zeros
    for (long j = 1 ; j < b.length(); j ++){
    result = result + b[j];
    }

    InfInt final = *new InfInt();
    final.initFromBinary(result);
    return final;
}

InfInt InfInt::operator>>(const InfInt& a) const {
    std::string b = this->getBinary();

    b.erase(1, (int) a);

    InfInt final = *new InfInt();
    final.initFromBinary(b);
    return final;
}
```

Comment: I see a lot of `new`  and `*new` statements but not a single `delete` in that code, which is [a memory leak or undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16879995/480982). This code is dangerous.

This implementation has other issues as well, like narrowing conversions (`size_t` to UL, ULL to UL) signed/unsigned conversion (UL to L), comparisons of different types (L to ULL).

Answer (score 6):

You can create a big integer in exactly the way you describe. In fact, the first time I implemented such a class, that's exactly the way I did it. It helped me implement the arithmetic operations (`+`, `-`, etc) since it was in the base (10) that I was used to.

A natural enhancement to your "array of chars" is to keep it in base 10, but use 4 bits for the digit, instead of the whole byte. Thus, the number 123,456 might be represented by the bytes `12 34 56` instead of the string `123456`. (Three bytes as opposed to six.)

From there, you could make the storage for the number in base two. The basic arithmetic operations such as addition work exactly the same in base 2 as they do in base 10. Thus, the number 65565 could be stored using the bytes `FF FF`. (In a vector of `unsigned char`s, for example.) Some implementations of BigInts use larger chunks, such as `short` or `long`, for efficiency.

Base-10 big ints can be useful if you're doing a lot of displaying and/or serializing to base-10, and want to avoid the conversion to base-2.