# Big integer in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, bigint

I was working on a factorial program, and the program didn't work when trying to find the factorial of 1000. I think big integers are the solution; how do they work? (In either C or C++)

Answer (score 7):

[GMP](http://gmplib.org/) can do `bigint` operations for both C and C++. The documentation on that site is a good introduction, if you use the C++ classes they behave almost exactly like built-in primitive types.

Answer (score 5):

Look for the GMP. See the other question regarding this topic:

- [Handling very large Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124332/c-handling-very-large-integers)
- [C++ Big Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507121/c-big-integer)