# Data type to store value <=10^20 in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Is there any data type that is capable of storing values within range 0<**X**<10^20 in c/c++??

Comment: [For C++: boost::multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: The `double` type is available, unless you want full 20-digit precision.

Comment: *Exactly* that range, i.e. 10^20 + 1 would overflow? Or just "large enough to hold those values"? Also, integral or floating point?

Comment: Please do some googling before asking your questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827538/big-integer-in-c-or-c

Comment: Is this an XY-question, where you are asking this, but you are actually trying to solve a different question?

Comment: Just storing, or doing calculations on it too? `unsigned char[9]`? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `float` and a `double` can store values in the range you have specified, and beyond.

Note that it cannot store the precise discrete integers in that range, merely an approximation that is often relevant to the order of magnitude.

Answer (score 12):

Since `log2(10^20) = ~66.43` you will need an integer made by `128` bits to store the number with integer precision. Actually, as pointed out by delnan in comment, `67` bits would be sufficient, by rounding to `72` bits with 8 bits alignment or `96` bits with 32 bits alignment.

So, if you don't require an exact integer representation, you could use a `float` or a `double`, otherwise you could look for a arbitrary long number library (there are many available either for C or C++).

Comment: To nitpick, 67 bits are sufficient. More realistically, you might round up to 72 bit (9 bytes) if space is premium, or 96 bit (12 byte) for 32 bit alignment.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about "standard" size for integer types which usually just get twice the number of bits. Let me specify it.

Comment: Why is it that ~2x the minimum bits are required to get integer precision?

Comment: @AlexanderChristiansson the existing integral types are commonly 8-16-32-64 bits long so the next step in that series would be 128, twice 64.

Answer (score 2):

Both `float` and `double` can store numbers of range at least `1E-37` to `1E+37`.

If you need exact precision, you can use a big num library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org).

Comment: This shortchanges the ranges of `float` and `double` by an infinite amount, since their actual ranges (with IEEE 754) are from –∞ to +∞.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Here I refer to C requirements for minimum max value and maximum min value. But assuming `float` is `binary32` IEEE 754  type, the range is from `~ 1.18 × 10^−38` to `~ 3.4 × 10^38` according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format Do I miss something?

Comment: The Wikipedia page is wrong. It notes that infinity can be encoded with an exponent of 0xff (for 32-bit floating-point) but also says the maximum representable value is about 3.4e38. Obviously infinity is greater than 3.4e38. Since both –∞ and +∞ are representable, the range of representable values is –∞ to +∞.

Comment: @EricPostpischil and what about the range between 3.4e38 to –∞? If you cannot represent numbers in that range, you cannot say the range is –∞ to +∞.

Comment: What about the range between the largest representable finite value and the second largest? That is a span of 20,282,409,603,651,670,423,947,251,286,016. By your reasoning, if you cannot represent numbers in that range, you cannot say the range is –340282346638528859811704183484516925440 to +340282346638528859811704183484516925440. Continuing in that way implies that no representation is possible if it uses discrete values.

Answer (score 2):

`float` or
`double` can store the range you desire. You can also use a [Big Integer library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C%2B%2B_multiple_precision_arithmetic_libraries). Here's an example:

```cpp
// header files

#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Bigint {
    // representations and structures
    string a; // to store the digits
    int sign; // sign = -1 for negative numbers, sign = 1 otherwise

    // constructors
    Bigint() {} // default constructor
    Bigint( string b ) { (*this) = b; } // constructor for string

    // some helpful methods
    int size() { // returns number of digits
        return a.size();
    }
    Bigint inverseSign() { // changes the sign
        sign *= -1;
        return (*this);
    }
    Bigint normalize( int newSign ) { // removes leading 0, fixes sign
        for( int i = a.size() - 1; i > 0 && a[i] == '0'; i-- )
            a.erase(a.begin() + i);
        sign = ( a.size() == 1 && a[0] == '0' ) ? 1 : newSign;
        return (*this);
    }

    // assignment operator
    void operator = ( string b ) { // assigns a string to Bigint
        a = b[0] == '-' ? b.substr(1) : b;
        reverse( a.begin(), a.end() );
        this->normalize( b[0] == '-' ? -1 : 1 );
    }

    // conditional operators
    bool operator < ( const Bigint &b ) const { // less than operator
        if( sign != b.sign ) return sign < b.sign;
        if( a.size() != b.a.size() )
            return sign == 1 ? a.size() < b.a.size() : a.size() > b.a.size();
        for( int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) if( a[i] != b.a[i] )
            return sign == 1 ? a[i] < b.a[i] : a[i] > b.a[i];
        return false;
    }
    bool operator == ( const Bigint &b ) const { // operator for equality
        return a == b.a && sign == b.sign;
    }



    // mathematical operators
    Bigint operator + ( Bigint b ) { // addition operator overloading
        if( sign != b.sign ) return (*this) - b.inverseSign();
        Bigint c;
        for(int i = 0, carry = 0; i<a.size() || i<b.size() || carry; i++ ) {
            carry+=(i<a.size() ? a[i]-48 : 0)+(i<b.a.size() ? b.a[i]-48 : 0);
            c.a += (carry % 10 + 48);
            carry /= 10;
        }
        return c.normalize(sign);
    }
    Bigint operator - ( Bigint b ) { // subtraction operator overloading
        if( sign != b.sign ) return (*this) + b.inverseSign();
        int s = sign; sign = b.sign = 1;
        if( (*this) < b ) return ((b - (*this)).inverseSign()).normalize(-s);
        Bigint c;
        for( int i = 0, borrow = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {
            borrow = a[i] - borrow - (i < b.size() ? b.a[i] : 48);
            c.a += borrow >= 0 ? borrow + 48 : borrow + 58;
            borrow = borrow >= 0 ? 0 : 1;
        }
        return c.normalize(s);
    }
    Bigint operator * ( Bigint b ) { // multiplication operator overloading
        Bigint c("0");
        for( int i = 0, k = a[i] - 48; i < a.size(); i++, k = a[i] - 48 ) {
            while(k--) c = c + b; // ith digit is k, so, we add k times
            b.a.insert(b.a.begin(), '0'); // multiplied by 10
        }
        return c.normalize(sign * b.sign);
    }
    Bigint operator / ( Bigint b ) { // division operator overloading
        if( b.size() == 1 && b.a[0] == '0' ) b.a[0] /= ( b.a[0] - 48 );
        Bigint c("0"), d;
        for( int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++ ) d.a += "0";
        int dSign = sign * b.sign; b.sign = 1;
        for( int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            c.a.insert( c.a.begin(), '0');
            c = c + a.substr( i, 1 );
            while( !( c < b ) ) c = c - b, d.a[i]++;
        }
        return d.normalize(dSign);
    }
    Bigint operator % ( Bigint b ) { // modulo operator overloading
        if( b.size() == 1 && b.a[0] == '0' ) b.a[0] /= ( b.a[0] - 48 );
        Bigint c("0");
        b.sign = 1;
        for( int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            c.a.insert( c.a.begin(), '0');
            c = c + a.substr( i, 1 );
            while( !( c < b ) ) c = c - b;
        }
        return c.normalize(sign);
    }



    // output method
    void print() {
        if( sign == -1 ) putchar('-');
        for( int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) putchar(a[i]);
    }
};

int main() {
    Bigint a, b, c; // declared some Bigint variables

    /////////////////////////
    // taking Bigint input //
    /////////////////////////
    string input; // string to take input

    cin >> input; // take the Big integer as string
    a = input; // assign the string to Bigint a

    cin >> input; // take the Big integer as string
    b = input; // assign the string to Bigint b

    //////////////////////////////////
    // Using mathematical operators //
    //////////////////////////////////

    c = a + b; // adding a and b
    c.print(); // printing the Bigint
    puts(""); // newline

    c = a - b; // subtracting b from a
    c.print(); // printing the Bigint
    puts(""); // newline

    c = a * b; // multiplying a and b
    c.print(); // printing the Bigint
    puts(""); // newline

    c = a / b; // dividing a by b
    c.print(); // printing the Bigint
    puts(""); // newline

    c = a % b; // a modulo b
    c.print(); // printing the Bigint
    puts(""); // newline

    /////////////////////////////////
    // Using conditional operators //
    /////////////////////////////////

    if( a == b ) puts("equal"); // checking equality
    else puts("not equal");

    if( a < b ) puts("a is smaller than b"); // checking less than operator

    return 0;
}
```

I collect this sample library from [here](http://lightoj.com/article_show.php?article=1004). Maybe it will help you to build your own.

Answer (score 1):

The `double` type can hold some values up to that range, but it can't represent *all integers* in that range (because as noted in one of the other answers, you would need 67 bits to represent all such integers while a double has only 52 bits of mantissa).

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.80).aspx

float and double data types would be the answer. But moreover I think DOUBLE data type is ideal.