# Language for working on big numbers

Tags: biginteger

I am working on a task that consists different operations on very big numbers. Example : Multiplying two 50 digit numbers. That big-sized numbers cannot be handled using `C`.

Can someone suggest me some programming language that can handle operations on such types of big numbers without using any special type of libraries, so that I can learn that language to implement my algorithm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827538/big-integer-in-c-or-c

Comment: You can do that with any language you want. You just need to find a library for arbitrary precision arithmetic for that language. Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software

Comment: I don't want to use any special library

Comment: In that case just use Python. It's the easiest option.

Comment: Yeah, I am on it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python3 can work on very large numbers (you can say it has almost no limit) and that's automatic.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604998/3156085

You can try it yourself by entering very large numbers in python shell.

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal class from Java can work with large numbers as you need, without using any extra library.