# How to add, subtract, multiply and divide 2 numbers each containing 100 digits in C? (using arrays)

Tags: c, arrays

I'am trying to write a C code to add, subtract, multiply and divide 2 numbers each containing 100 digits. This should include the use of arrays.

Can anyone please give me any suggestions, a pseudo code or a sample code?
To be more clear 
The user will enter 2 numbers(Integers)
Each number can comprise of 100 or less digits i.e integer a can be 10 or 234 or 43582 or 23456788 or 23445667788...... etc. Same for integer b.
Now taking these two integers I have to perform the arithmetic operations of Addition,Subtraction,Division,Multiplication,Modulas(%)

Comment: @brunch875 which standard data type in C can store a 100 digit number? I think none. He wants to implement something like BigInt himself and asks for pointers as to how to get started.

Comment: For multiplication you can use the Karatsuba algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm
Addition should be fairly easy, just have to carry over the carry bit to the next array element.

Comment: @brunch875 try fitting a 100-digit number in a data type in C

Comment: @Guillaume: According to Henry F, you can fit any number of digits in an `int` type, as long as they are all leading zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the [GMP Library](http://gmplib.org/) as answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4827566/2328514). It can perform `Bigint` operations in both `C` and `C++`. Also if you are fine with `C++` code for `Bigint` you could check out this [blogpost](http://zobayer.blogspot.in/2010/03/small-bigint-library.html).

Comment: hi Rahul,can you explain this a bit more please.What is the GMP Library used for??

Comment: @caitancorreia try this [pdf](http://www-oldurls.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/lect/mssemi/reports/01_rep_DiyoraSalimova.pdf). Please search some more about it, i am sure you will find what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for hints on implementing arbitrary precision arithmetic. Start be reading this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic , then search for `bignum c code` with a search engine, sample implementations are easy to find.  Avoid full blown packages such as gnu MP because they are too advanced and not the right starting point.