# consider x^i+y^i=z^i x<=y<=z<=m and 2<=i<=n (m and n are inputs) m can vary from 5 to 100 n can vary from 2 to 100

Tags: c, optimization, project

consider `x^i+y^i=z^i`, `x<=y<=z<=m` and `2<=i<=n`
(m and n are inputs)
m can vary from 5 to 100
n can vary from 2 to 100

How can i aproach this problem.? I've a solution but it's not feasible for values of n and m  like 80 or more and starts giving wrong results :(

```
int main()
{
  int m, n;
  long long int x, y, z, j;
  long long int xe, ye, ze, se;
  long long int sum = 0;
  scanf("%d", &m);
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (j = 2; j <= n; j++)
  {
    for (x = 0; x <= m; x++)
    {
      for (y = x; y <= m; y++)
      {
        for (z = y; z <= m; z++)
        {
          xe = pow(x, j);
          ye = pow(y, j);
          ze = pow(z, j);
          se = (xe + ye);
          if (ze == se)
          {
            printf("\n i = %lld", j);
            sum++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("sum= %lld ", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you would need something that can handle big integers. See for example [Big integer in C or C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827538/big-integer-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 2):

You need an implementation of a Big Integer in C, as your predicted Results can get higher than the normal Integer, even the `long long int` is capable of storing. You can either write one yourself or use one that has already been written, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827538/big-integer-in-c-or-c).