# Data type in C language for value 12000000000

Tags: c

I want a datatype that can hold the value 12,000,000,000 (twelve billion) in C. Which datatype does accept this value?

I have tried `long int` and `long long int` for it.

Comment: Have a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827538/big-integer-in-c-or-c

Comment: Isn't that twelve _billion_? `long long` should work just fine; it is supposed to have at least 64 bits. What problems did you have?

Comment: What is the format specifier used for uint64_t?

Comment: @AniketSaxena, `PRI64u` from `inttypes.h`, but that shouldn't be your problem. If you use `long long` use the format `%llu`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8132399/10077.

Comment: @AniketSaxena see my updated answer

Comment: long long is not working.

Comment: Please suggest the datatype and format specifier for the value 12000000000 and a[12000000000]…

Comment: I am using gcc-4.4.2 compiler for it...

Answer (score 2):

12,000,000,000 can certainly fit in a `long long` and higher ranking types as `long long` is specified to have a range *at least* [−(2^63 − 1) ... +(2^63 − 1)] or `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

```
long long twelve_mil = 12000000000;  // No suffix needed
```

Lower ranking types like `unsigned long`, `long` , `unsigned`, `int` *may* also work.  Example: C specifies that a `long` has a *minimum* range of [-2147483647 ... +2147483647], but it may be more.

```
#if 12000000000 >= INT_MAX
  int twelve_mil = 12000000000;
  printf("%d\n", twelve_mil);
#elif 12000000000 >= LONG_MAX
  long twelve_mil = 12000000000;  
  printf("%ld\n", twelve_mil);
#else 
  long long twelve_mil = 12000000000;  
  printf("%lld\n", twelve_mil);
#endif
```

We could extend this to consider even lower ranking types like  `unsigned short`, `short` , `unsigned char` `signed char` and even `char`.  Not fruitful on many machines.

Code could consider using `int64_t`.  That common, yet *optional* type is defined in `#include <stdint.h>`.  Also declared there is `int_least64_t`, which is always available since C99.

```
#include <stdint.h>

// for format specifiers
#include <inttypes.h>

int_least64_t twelve_mil = 12000000000;
printf("%" PRIdLEAST64 "\n", twelve_mil);
// or
int64_t twelve_mil = 12000000000;  // Commonly available
printf("%" PRId64 "\n", twelve_mil);
```

Comment: How could I declare a[12000000000] in C.

Comment: And what is the format specifier for that.

Comment: @AniketSaxena I recommend you to become familiar with the very basics of C at a tutorial site. http://www.learn-c.org/ is a great place to start.

Comment: @Aniket Saxena To declare such a  large array, some platforms may accept `some_type a[12000000000];`   Many will not.  Allocating is the next consideration.  `some_type *a = malloc(sizeof *a * 12000000000);`.  With array size and allocations, code should use the type `size_t`.  `size_t  sz = 12000000000; some_type *a = malloc(sizeof *a * sz);`  If `SIZE_MAX < 12000000000`, then other approaches are needed.

Comment: OK but please suggest me the answer for that...

Comment: @AniketSaxena Unclear on "what is the format specifier for that".. What is "that" and for which function is code applying the desired format specifier?  Code does not _need_ a suffix to express 12000000000.  Just code `long long sz = 12000000000;`

Comment: @AniketSaxena concerning `a[12000000000]`: best to append that question to your post rather that only request info on it in comments.

Comment: @chux It seems to me that the OP is working on a homework and he only wants some instant solutions instead of taking time to learn about the language. It's hard to help if the other peer doesn't show any effort to help himself.

Comment: @plasmacel Yes - of course - yet  I was simply being patient - we've all been in a hurry sometimes.  It could take some time for OP to respond.

Comment: Actually the signals are not coming well here in my area that's why I am responding late...

Comment: I do not think they are _late_.   Proceed at your pace.

Comment: OK I will post the question for a[12000000000] bcoz when I run the program it shows me a dialog box:A problem caused the program to stop correctly.

Comment: @AniketSaxena  Did you try the suggestions in this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662720/data-type-in-c-language-for-value-12000000000/38663932?noredirect=1#comment64709019_38663932)?  How did the 2 ideas work for you?  Code  likely needs to allocate memory.  What _type_ is your array?

Answer (score 0):

Use `long long int` and `unsigned long long int`, or the fixed size versions `int64_t` and `uint64_t` located in `stdint.h`. The unsigned versions has twice the max value of the signed ones. Any of them can hold your desired value.

```
long long int x0 = 12000000000ll;
unsigned long long int x1 = 12000000000ull;
```

or

```
#include "stdint.h"

int64_t x0 = 12000000000ll;
uint64_t x1 = 12000000000ull;
```

You can print the signed long long as `printf("%lld", x0);`, and the unsigned long long as `printf("%llu", x1);`.

You can also read more about the size and value range of numeric types at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

Comment: Why would a `long int` not work in this case?

Comment: @DanielMargosian `long int` might be the same size as `int`. Also it can not be hold in `int32_t`.

Comment: `long int` is usually `int32_t` on most systems. the standard says that `long int` must be at least 32 bits long. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be

Comment: You don't need the suffixes for the constants. You should link to a C answer. Oh, and those are minimum ranges, not the actual ranges.

Comment: The size of the numeric types are the same in C and C++. It would be a disaster if it were not. On the other hand it's a good practice to use suffixes. It's error prone and indicates the order of magnitude of a value.

Comment: Even if the *minimum ranges* for integer types are the same, it is still a different language.

Comment: The standard only specifies the minimum ranges. The answer to the OP's question is perfectly covered by the link. I update my answer and link the MSDN reference of fundamental types, where C/C++ types are also discussed together...

Comment: The msdn link is actually incorrect about the ranges.

Comment: @2501 Feel free to update my answer with a reliable link of detailed description of fundamental C types, which doesn't mention C++ and lists size and range of each type. I feel it a pointless nitpicking at this point.

Comment: I can do that if you mark the answer as a community answer.

Comment: unit_64 is not working

Comment: @AniketSaxena Where did you see `unit_64` in my answer?

Comment: Oops sorry!! I mean uint64_t

Comment: @AniketSaxena I think you don't print the value properly. Use `printf("%llu", x1);`.

Comment: long long is working for a=12000000000 but not for a[12000000000]…please answer me how to resolve it…

Comment: What you mean it doesn't work? You get a compilation error? Runtime error? If you want to declare an array of 12000000000 elements, then you need to specify the type of the array elements like: `char a[12000000000];`. This is an array of 12000000000 `char` values. If you exceed the maximum size of the memory you get runtime error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386979/the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-c

Comment: The msg in the dialog box I got: A problem caused the program to stop correctly.