# Correct way of adding vectors and numbers

Tags: c++

Suppose you want to add some huge numbers

```
int add(int &a, int b){
    return a = a+b;
}
int add_(int a, int b){
    int c = a+b;
    return c;
}
```

This is what I have in my mind. I was actually thinking about adding two vectors then I generalized it to numbers. If you want to use the `add` style, what will you do if you need the original value of `a`? And if you want to use the `add_` style, isn't it memory waste if you have to add, subtract and multiply a lot of large numbers?

What is the standard way of doing this?

Comment: I am afraid there's no _"standard way"_ to do that.

Comment: At least a common approach? @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: There are libraries specialized for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "need the original value of `a`"? Before you call a function, you already have that value. If you want to destroy it inside `add`, make a copy before you call that function. Take a look at LAPACK interface, for example.

Comment: After passing it by reference add(a, 1), and you will have new a value which is a+1. And if you want to pass 'a' again after calling add function, for example: add(a, 1) you will be passing a+1 rather than original 'a' itself @Evg

Comment: Your first try with the reference is clearly wrong, you don't want to change your inputs and reference allow implementation to change a. So I would write it as `vector add(const vector& v1, const vector& v2) { return { v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y}; }` The `const`'s are there to say you're not going to change v1 and v2, and the references are there to avoid unecessary copy of v1 and v2

Comment: `add(a, b)` that modifies either `a` or `b` is semantically broken. It doesn't model addition and should be called by some other name.

Comment: What do you mean by adding "vectors and numbers"? What are "huge numbers"? Are you asking about [big integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507121/c-big-integer) implementation?

Comment: Can you explain? I don't know about the terminology but it returns a + b anyway @Evg

Comment: Suppose you have two `int`s `a` and `b`. Will `a + b` modify them? No. Follow the same rule for your data types. An operation that modifies `a` is `a += b`. You can replace `+=` with a plain function, but it should not have a name `add` - your code should be readable and understandable by people. For the same reason you won't use a name `mul` or `div` for `a + b`, although technically you could.

Comment: Use two separate functions named `operator +` and `operator +=`.