# How to get arbitrarily large numbers in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, arbitrary-precision

I need a way to use very very large data types. Whereas an int is typically 4 bytes, I need a data type of 536, 870, 912 bytes or maybe even higher. I can't just use an array because I need to be able to convert to string, add, subtract, multiply, divide, etc with them.

How can I create or use such a large data type? I'd need a uint4294967296_t :P

Note I have tried using structs with bitfields, but they aren't large enough and I can't convert between values using that.

Comment: Use a [library](https://gmplib.org/), perhaps?

Comment: Greg is referring to the GIMP library, which is usually recommended for this.

Comment: Voting to close because recommendations of libraries is currently off-topic on SO.

Comment: You have several options, including GMP: https://gmplib.org/, or create your own class.  This question has been asked several times on SO, including [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310276/how-to-handle-arbitrarily-large-integers) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685799/arbitrary-size-integers-in-c-c).

Comment: If you want to perform the multi-precision math yourself, then I suggest you take a look at Donald Knuth's [Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming). I believe Volume II, Seminumerical Algorithms, Chapter 4, Multiple Precision Arithmetic, is what you are interested in. Also see [How to add 2 arbitrarily sized integers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2926219/608639), which provides code for some C++ libraries and OpenSSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Bignumber library, I prefer TTMath for its simplicity. You can find it here [Link to tttmath](http://www.ttmath.org/). TTTmath allows for operation on large numbers but You may need to make your own toString method.

Here is an example of TTTmath in use from their [Samples](http://www.ttmath.org/samples) page:

```
#include <ttmath/ttmath.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
ttmath::UInt<2> a,b,c;

    a = "1234";
    b = 3456; 
    c = a*b;

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
Listing nr 1
```

Comment: Recommendation of a library should be a comment, not an answer. Flagged this as such. (That means, hopefully a mod will convert it to a comment.)

Comment: Why? He didn't ask how to implement big numbers, but how to use them. So a library recommendation should be a valid answer imo.

Comment: Questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic on SO (it's one of the stock close reasons).

Comment: Seems to be a bit nitpicky to me if a library is the only sane way to solve the problem at hand. And he actually didn't ask for a library recommendation but described his problem which would be in line with http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @zett42: I agree it would be useful with these kinds of questions on SO, but such are the current rules. I think because it's always possible to add new different answers, an arbitrarily long sequence of recommendations. E.g. the C++ book list FAQ, a really useful question, suffered from this problem and was converted to a less useful format.

Comment: I will include an implementation so that I meet the community standards. Thanks for the heads up.