# How to access bignumber functionality from crypto?

Tags: node.js, openssl, biginteger

Some time ago I explored the big number functionality that come embedded in OpenSSL (available - for instance - by `#include <openssl/bn.h>`), and I'd like to use it in node. As I understand it, OpenSSL get exposed via crypto library module, but I can't figure how to access it, albeit - I think - it should be available. At least, it appears in [github](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn).

Any hint available ?

Comment: Related, see [How to add 2 arbitrarily sized integers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2926500/608639). Its not Node.js specific, however.