# Why the second number is always 0?

Tags: c++

I have a problem and I don't seem to find a solution.
I have this long number:

> 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
>   46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
>   74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
>   91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
>   23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676
>   89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757
>   28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738
>   44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318
>   47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276
>   70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951
>   62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331
>   64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178
>   92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407
>   58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828
>   80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390
>   35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586
>   86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829
>   71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938
>   54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604
>   53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145
>   36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721
>   45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045
>   17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412
>   81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692
>   51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483
>   62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691
>   15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209
>   55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126
>   18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515
>   80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954
>   78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581
>   16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984
>   48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030
>   87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332
>   59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210
>   69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085
>   41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271
>   65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375
>   35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307
>   94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275
>   88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271
>   25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526
>   36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962
>   24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141
>   91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403
>   34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470
>   23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583
>   11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470
>   63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533
>   67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822
>   95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774
>   76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236
>   37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967
>   23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522
>   29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501
>   18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715
>   38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381
>   34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539
>   40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635
>   29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903
>   41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922
>   62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457
>   23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519
>   86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672
>   11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308
>   82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581
>   97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500
>   42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327
>   55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789
>   32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886
>   75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337
>   62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731
>   32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504
>   99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622
>   73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724
>   76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818
>   97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852
>   87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090
>   10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786
>   71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039
>   62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116
>   66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411
>   60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714
>   85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096
>   66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297
>   64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252
>   16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011
>   94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791
>   78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699
>   15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078
>   40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353
>   44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535
>   41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954
>   81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280
>   82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608
>   22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197
>   77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617
>   72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516
>   20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722
>   53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690

I take it as a string and convert to int, but no matter what I do, for some reason i always get the second number as a 0 and it's as if it's not even existant. I think it doesn't even convert it or something else happens I'm not sure. Depending on what i cout, I get these 2 answers: https://imgur.com/a/OiDIo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string String_Numbers[50], num;
    int Int_Numbers[50];
    ifstream DM("data.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        getline(DM, num);
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            num = num[i];
            Int_Numbers[i] = atoi(num.c_str());
            cout << Int_Numbers[i] << "";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    DM.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for inconveniences, for some reason my code didn't save first time when i posted.

And btw, I'm converting every single digit to integer not the whole number.

Comment: Please copy and paste (the relevant parts of) code here. Don't post links to other sites, which may go dead, or post images of code, which can't be used by others to search for your question if they have a similar one.

Comment: There is no way that you can fit such a big number in INT.

Comment: Overflowing an `int` is *undefined behavior*. Maybe look at a bignum library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: You need a Big Integer library. For instance GMP or MPIR (for Windows). Both free.

Comment: Here are some examples for using popular libraries to work with extremely large numbers in C++:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940572/19719

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are around 5000+ digits in that number. The only possibility is to scan it in from of string or character array only.

But, We will perform the operations like addition, subtraction and multiplication even they are stored in character array.

```
char num1[5100];
char num2[5100];
vector <int> v;
```

then for addition :

```
  int carry=0;
  int ans;

  for (int i=last_digit;i>=0;i--) {
    ans=carry+num1[i]+num2[i];
    v.push_back(ans%10);
    carry=ans/10;
 }
 v.push_back(carry);
```

Like this we can do operation also. The reason you are not getting output any int datatype can't afford this much digits. Even, when you convert from a string to int.

Hope you got it !!

Comment: I get everything right except for some reason the second number is always 0. That is the only problem. Why is that?

Comment: I think you are using the same variable at ` num = num[ i ] ` Just try it with using another new variable ` string tmp ; ` and  `tmp=num[i] ` . got it ??

Answer (score 5):

I think you should check the limits of integers... For example [9,223,372,036,854,775,807](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9,223,372,036,854,775,807) is the maximum value of 64 bit (a.k.a. x64) architecture's signed integer... So your integer is [overflowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) (exceeding the maximum value, so it is reseting to the minimal value) multiple times...

Even the 128 bit integer wouldn't be enough for this number with it's maximum at 170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,727 (a long number).